# way to recieve message in out of the chat component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, chat

I need to have a real time message listener in react native
I have chat component when user login to chat component message's work correctly,
but when user A connect to chat but user B in home screen 
message don't receive by user B because websocket receive message only load in chat component.
so I want to have a global receive function for listen new message
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to work all around the app import your socket at the "App.js" , 
and create a function to store the messages in localstorage on receive parameter , i have tested this method it should work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You have two ways to do it.

1- Have your WebSocket linked to a component at the base of your app, with a listener on the `new_user_event` and pass add it to your store with an action. In the same way, you did in the chat component. your server when the

2- Is to check on the server-side if a user is connected or the chat screen is mounted (or the user is on the chat screen). If the user is not in the chat screen send a silent notification to app with the info of the new user

---

[Edit]

You need some kind of store to save data and share it between your screens. I could be redux or context or directly on the local storage of your app.

__

Another way which is not clean is to handle all the event in the base of the app and pass the data as props to the children

Comment: i dont use redux

Comment: @AkbarShahamati You need some kind of store to save data and share it between your screens. I could be redux or context or directly on the local storage of your app.

__

Another way which is not clean is to handle all the event in the base of the app and pass the data as props to the children